# Dynamic tooltip depending on mouse over on a row in a datagrid(NOT datagridview)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, tooltip, dataview

I am trying to make it so that when the user mouses over a row in my DataGrid / dataview, each row would display a different tooltip outcome.

I cannot really figure this out. with DataGrid how can I say mouseOver on each row and give row specific data? seems like all my usual online sources have turned up nothing!

not if there is a way to make this work with a datagridview I don't know how to populate it(datagridview) as my table varies in length every time the program runs. (the program keeps track of signals, so if more signals are recieved then the table has more rows...)

*** note: this is visual C# 2.0 in visual studios 2005 enviroment.

*** ended up with following:

```
private void datagridSignal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        this.toolTip.Hide(datagridSignal);
        this.toolTip.RemoveAll();
        DataTable dt = GetSignalTable();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        Point prop = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestInfo myHitTest;
        prop = datagridSignal.PointToClient(prop);
        myHitTest = datagridSignal.HitTest(prop.X, prop.Y);
        this.toolTip.SetToolTip(datagridSignal, " ID = '" + (int)dv[myHitTest.Row][0] + "' ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you handle MouseMove event on the grid? You can then transform coordinates of the mouse to the row handle and change  grid's tooltip accordingly.

Something like:

```
private void dataGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
 var point = dataGrid.PointToClient(e.X, e.Y);
 var hittest = dataGrid.HitTest(point.X, point.Y);
 toolTip1.SetToolTip(dataGrid, hittest.Row); // add Tooltip conotrol to the form!!!
}
```

Comment: how? if I did                                               DataGridSignal_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e) {             ??? ???                                     this.tooltip.settooltip(datagrid,(int)dz.Table.Columns.Count);                                                 } what do I put inside the function/method? this is the portion that I'm caught up on

Comment: ah, yeah I tried this once before, but I'm getting an error when trying to declair 'MouseEventArgs e' in the function parameters.

        private void dataGridCurrAlarms_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point prop = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            prop = dataGridCurrAlarms.PointToClient(prop);
            var hittest = dataGridCurrAlarms.HitTest(prop.X, prop.Y); 
            this.toolTip.SetToolTip(dataGridCurrAlarms, hittest.Row);
        }

is what I'm trying but still no good. var isn't a thing...

Comment: should have also mentioned I am in visual studio 2005. so I am using visual C# 2.0... no such thing as var

Comment: I don't remember what type of parameters this event has. But if you cannot use MouseEventArgs, replace 
`Point point = dataGrid.PointToClient(e.X, e.Y);` with `Point point = dataGrid.PointToClient(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.X);`

Comment: yeah it seems to compile w/ MouseEventArgs now, but I cant figure out what sort of variable hitTest is

Comment: found it:   System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestInfo myHitTest;

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in XAML:

```
<extToolkit:DataGrid Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <extToolkit:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type extToolkit:DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext.ID}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </extToolkit:DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <extToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                <extToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
                <extToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Data" Binding="{Binding FirstData}" />
                <extToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Second Data" Binding="{Binding SecondData}" />               
            </extToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        </extToolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about XAML or XML
what would I do with this?

Comment: You did not write earlier that it is .NET 2.0.  Sorry!